Can an html viewer render a react-web website in react-native, similar to electron for desktop apps?
This is probably too convenient to be true, otherwise I'd have seen it somewhere but it seems like nobody asked (at least with an easy to find wording) --
is it possible to develop a react web application, then plug it in react native through any html viewers (eg few options presented in Render HTML in React Native)?
if yes, what kind of problems should one expect (eg. performance, failing browser API calls, ...?)
if not, what prevents this to work? (eg. would part of the javascript code for react not run in react native for some reason, etc.)
as for why I would even consider doing that, I really like the idea that a single react repo could be made into a mobile app without much hussle this way, if this was made to work somehow.

React-Native is not the issue; browsers are the issue. Because the browser does not support React, you will need to bundle the application using the browser's bundler in order to view it in WebView or another third-party library.
You can use Esbuild, Parcel 2, Rollup, and other tools for bundlers.
